# How to collate string for mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I have a query that filters based on content from a website.  It usually works just fine, except for when it finds content that doesn't agree with the (default) collation I have on the table.  Is there a way, on Php's side, to adjust the collation?

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql CONVERT() and CAST()

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Comment: The problem is that blows away my index, I was hoping to do it on php's end.

Comment: ive had mixed results with iconv, mb_convert_encoding,utf8_encode. what are you converting from>to ?

Comment: Currently I'm having trouble matching a url that looks like it has hebrew chars to latin_swedish

Comment: you speak Latin? or Swedish? i wish utf8 was the default, it makes so much more sense, change to it, it will make your life easier in many ways